# Rails controller caching when using docker container (dev)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I have docker running an app container (rails app) and a db container running postgres

I have volume mounted my local working directory to my app container so I can work locally and the changes reflected in the app container.

In doing this everything seems to work fine except I seem to get some strange caching behaviour on my controllers

for example

route:

```
get '/something', to: 'something#show'
```

controller

```
class SomethingController < ApplicationController
    def show
        render text: "Hello 1"
    end
end
```

When I go to myapp/something I get `Hello 1` perfect!

Then I edit my controller to:

```
class SomethingController < ApplicationController
    def show
        render text: "Hello 2"
    end
end
```

When I go to myapp/something I still get `Hello 1`?

If I return a html view, it updates just fine, so why is my changes in my controller not being reflected?

The only way I can get these changes to reflect is by making a change in my routes file and saving, this seems to refresh whatever is being cached.

note: I am not caching in the browser, I have caching turned off and Im doing a hard reload each time.

Can anyone shed any light on this? Im trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEdDa3Zqu7s&list=PLbG4OyfwIxjEe5Y3hQCiQjYnSgRH051iJ&index=3

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How did you define your development.rb?

Make sure you have the caching options set to false:

```
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false
config.cache_classes = false
```

If this doesn't work you might want to read the Rails docs about caching:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: Frenus, You're a legend. Thank you so much. I had `config.cache_classes = false` but not `config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false` this seemed to solve the problem.